# JText .getText() returns nothing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm, trying to do a small app and now i need to take some data from a `JTextField` when i press a certain button. The problem is that when i press the button, nothing happens.. I tested it with a `println("yes")` and it`s working printing "yes' on`ActionListener`. What should i do ?

Here is a part of code:

```
label = new Label("Width:");
label.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(40, 25));
this.add(label);

textField = new TextField();
textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 25));
textField.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(80, 25));
this.add(textField);

button = new JButton("Submit");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        System.out.println(textField.getText()); // <- here textField.getText() does not return anything.
    }
});
this.add(button);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what components you are using, but i think you have a problem with components declaration, it should be :

```
textField = new JTextField();
label = new JLabel("Width:");
```

and not :

```
textField = new TextField();
label = new Label("Width:");

      JTextField() and not TextField()
//----^--------------------^---------------
```

Answer (score 1):

**TextField is part of awt**

```
textField = new TextField();
```

by this constructor, the specified text to be displayed is " ".

by `getText()` Returns the text contained in this TextComponent so you getting " " string.

**JTextField is part of swing**

```
textField = new JTextField();
```

by this constructor, the initial string to display is null

by `getText()` Returns the text contained in this TextComponent so you getting null.